# How to loop array object and re-assign value by condition in mongoDB aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a problem with mongo aggregate, please help.

First, I have a collection like that:

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "properties": [
   {
       key: "prop1",
       value: "propVal1",
   },
   {
       key: "prop2",
       value: "propVal2",
   },
   {
       key: "prop3",
       value: "propVal3",
   }
]
```

And a JS object like that:

```
const newKeyValues = [{ key: "prop1" , value: "newVal1" }, { key: "prop2" , value: "newVal2" }];
```

So how can I create an aggregate pipeline to set new value by key to `properties` array? The expected output of pipeline is something like this:

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "properties": [
   {
       key: "prop1",
       value: "newVal1",
   },
   {
       key: "prop2",
       value: "newVal2",
   },
   {
       key: "prop3",
       value: "propVal3",
   }
]
```

Thanks all.

Comment: You can use aggregation array operators like [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to iterate (or loop) and assign new values to each of the array elements.

Comment: Thank you @prasad_, I have researched about $map and find a way to resolve it. Please take a look below if we can do it better.

Comment: The solution you have just about looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer, need another JS function to map the value by `key`. But the query is built to something like:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $project: {
    id: "$id",
    properties: {
      $map: {
        input: "$properties",
        as: "properties",
        in: {
          key: "$$properties.key",
          value: {
            $switch: {
              branches: [
                {
                  case: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$properties.key",
                      "prop1"
                    ]
                  },
                  then: "newValue1"
                },
                {
                  case: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$properties.key",
                      "prop2"
                    ]
                  },
                  then: "newValue2"
                }
              ],
              default: "$$properties.value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```